# Can I collect and merge different answers into an accepted one?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Often answers to good questions grow in number and accuracy, and some details, warnings, or different approaches are not in the approved answer. Is it advisable to gather them into one collective answer? Who should be able to merge those answers and whom should be given the reputation points and bounty?

Comment: Why would you gather them in one answer? "accepted" is just the OP's checkmark. I never count it as more than just another upvote. Votes are a way better indicator of quality and consensus then that checkmark... people should stop focusing so much on it. If there's multiple approaches, I'd think leaving them in separate answers is less confusing then mashing everything together.

Comment: Consider a math problem that has different good solutions using calculus, or a discrete or several geometric approaches: there's no obvious better answer. Or maybe a programming question that may be solved using many libraries each with its advantages and drawbacks: the simple fact that one answer has more upvotes may simply mean that one library is more utilized, but may be not suitable for every project. Or consider a question asking which are all the model variations that has been made of one particular product: the top answer may have identified 12 out of the 17 that have been answered.

Comment: The accept mark is supposed to be an indicator of what worked for the OP. Adding approaches the OP didn't actually use to the accepted answer is counter to that.

Comment: *Or consider a question asking which are all the model variations that has been made of one particular product:* - That question would likely get closed for being off topic.

Comment: Claudio, if there's no "obvious" better answer, people will upvote based off what they use and think is correct. So over time there will be a better answer. Honestly I don't see why having info in multiple answers is a bad thing.

Comment: _That question would likely get closed for being off topic_: really? Just some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511102/how-many-types-of-cloning-an-object-are-available-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25786808/how-many-types-of-branches-exist-in-git, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65925/how-many-items-can-produce-light, http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8214/what-physical-and-mental-attributes-do-i-need-to-become-a-pilot/, http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/16813/how-many-demon-forms-does-mirajane-have ...

Comment: Claudio, there is ONE relevant question here. Those not on stack overflow don't mean at thing, as other sites have different rules. One of the stack question is from 4 years ago, which means you shouldn't use it as a guide for your own questions.

Comment: I don't see the point in downvoting this question. Since I am asking if this is advisable or not, if you think it's not, please reply *why* and *what* is the correct behavior when facing this situation. After all, this is the purpose of a _meta_ forum :/

Comment: Please don't start this discussion. People vote differently on meta, and it doesn't affect your rep. Since you tagged the question as "feature request", voting also determines if people think this should be implemented or not. Seems that people don't think it should, from voting

Comment: (anyway I see 4 downvotes, and answers from me, BSMP, Serge, and durron.... 4 downvotes, 4 people... sounds like it's possible that you got an answer from every downvoter here)

Comment: @Patrice: Sorry if it disappoints you but I didn't downvote here :-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta not very important for the point I was making :P and now that there are 6 downvotes, this is moot anyway

Comment: I think there should be a tool helping to merge answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, there one single case where merging answers would make sense: if they complete each other. I mean, all are acceptable answers, but each missed a particular point and you really need pieces from all to build a correct solution.

In that case, and if none of the previous answerers has done it, you could write a new answer, **explicitely giving credit** to the answers you use to build yours. To really be fair, you should even make that answer a community wiki. That way:

- you improve the site by putting all relevant points in one single answer, helping future readers to use it
- you cannot be blamed for plagiarism

But if you make the new answer a community wiki (what you should do unless you really add value to the other answers), you won't earn any reputation.

Comment: Thank you for bringing my attention to the Community Wiki feature, since this was exactly what I was wondering about. I've found a very interesting and close-related post here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down, and it's worth noticing that _"End users can not mark questions wiki anymore, so the only appropriate way to get action on a question you believe really should be wiki, is to flag it for moderator attention"_

Comment: I was looking up this after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649253/why-xml-file-is-not-rendered-properly-in-firefox (a good example where answers should be merged IMHO): It seems some plugins cause a problem, and people add a new answer for every plugin they found. I think all those plugins should be collected in a single answer and preferably the true origin of the problem should be stated.

Answer (score 4):

If there are many answers with value, even if they are completely different, **upvote them all**.

A future reader coming across your question will see these higher scores (and see other answers, perhaps that have low score because they weren't upvoted) and read them and then choose which approach works best for their exact situation.

I don't see any value in merging answers slightly visually closer together, but I do see harm in that such merges would actively damage the reputation system where each answerer can be rewarded for their good work.